# Metamask is not connecting my blockchain network

Tags: blockchain, metamask

I'm building a todoList Web-App using blockchain. I'm stuck when I tried to connect the `blockchain server` to metamask.
When I try to add new network as mentioned in my **Ganache**(HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545) then I miss chainID and When I fill the chainID with **Genache** network Id it shows the given error.
[image]

When I try to connect to `localhost8545` then it returns this error:
[image]

trufle-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
}
```

How can I connect my blockchain network with my localhost?

Comment: Can you please share your ganache config file

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to chain id 5777? Use 1337 as the chain id by default. I don't see where you've set the chain id to be 5777

Comment: I tried it on metamask not in my code!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove default localhost account (i.e. Localhost 8545 ) first and then add the new network with details and chain ID as 1337

Comment: You needn't delete localhost 8545. You'd just need to set the chain id as 1337 instead of 5777

Answer (score 2):

- Open metamask extenuation settings
- find there network
- click on it
- find localhost 8545
- remove it
- try create new with 1337

Comment: thanks for your answer @armen.. but this looks pretty same as above one

Answer (score 0):

I am greeting same error but I tried this and i got the solution
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVzp4.png]
I am changing the host name to localhost and it work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).